# Are questions about Drupal issues with specific host providers on-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4768/how-do-you-deal-with-the-admin-page-and-godaddy

The OP is asking for a work-around for an issue he has with a host provider.
In the specific, the question seems on-topic because

- The OP is using Drupal, and while reporting the issue to the host provider is what I would do, the OP is probably interested to know a work-around that avoid the problem in the short time. I would tell him to report the issue to the host provider, as it is probable they need to change settings, or they already had a similar report and they already know what to do.
- The problem is specific with Drupal, as Drupal uses paths beginning with "admin."

Are such questions on-topic? When those questions stop to be on-topic?
If the question is not already listed in the off-topic questions, and it is off-topic, should it be added as example of off-topic question?

Comment: this could probably be generalized into "are questions about Drupal issues with specific host providers on topic?"

Comment: I changed the question to make it more general. Doing so, I did something I suggested not to do in an answer of mine. `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

You could probably reword the question to make it into something that is Drupal related; the question as asked has nothing to do with Drupal. It might as well be about Django or any other system.

Also most likely the solution is placed at Godaddy rather than Drupal. Ask them to unlock admin, or maybe it's just a setting turned on by the user - like some sort of IP address access control etc.

We have to find a balance not blasting new users away and not using a lot of resources to make a half hearted attempt into a valid question.

Also worth mentioning, the question asked has asked almost 300  drupal questions on SO with a total of about 200 upvotes. This track record was also taking into account.

Comment: What you do in Drupal to set a path alias is different from what you do in Django, if Django really has the equivalent of path aliases used in Drupal; therefore, the workaround is specific to Drupal.

Comment: Also, Drupal has the concept of clean URLs, while other CMSes just have a URL schema. If the work-around is to disable the clean URLs, then the work-around is specific to Drupal. Indeed, the OP should open a ticket on Godaddy, but that doesn't mean he is interested to a work-around. This is different from asking a work-around for a module bug, because in this case, for Godaddy is not a bug.

Comment: @kia My point is that the exact same question with no modification could have been asked on my-CMS.SE. That you can fix a problem with Drupal doesn't necessarily make the problem relevant on this site.

Comment: On my-CMS.SE, you probably don't get an answer that is specific for Drupal. Following your example, then all the questions on DA would be migrated to Stack Overflow. If I am interested in a work-around to use with Drupal because that is the only work-around I can apply in the short time, where should I ask the question, on a site where Drupal is only marginally known?

Answer (score -2):

Yes.